# ipn using customer business pp account

Tags: paypal-ipn

my ipn works perfectly its setup under our business PayPal account. our asp.net website is being used by multiple customers with their own members, unique by their login. as of now the cart writes to our database with the orders and sets a status code that gets changed to 'completed' via the ipn call/authentication from PayPal using our PayPal email. now, a couple want to use their own PayPal accounts, non-for profits, so in order for this to work as previously described what changes in the post variables?

ex of what i need: a member of our customer logs in to our website, adds items to their cart and chooses PayPal payment option. it writes to our database as an 'in-process' order. **it opens our customer PayPal account to complete the payments then once complete it calls our ipn setup under our PayPal account** and redirects back to the custom page.

again, everything is already working great just want to call their own PayPal account instead of ours w/o needing to have them setup the ipn settings under their account, but use the ipn setup under our PayPal account. members see their own customer PayPal account billing theme and the money is in their account not ours. is this possible?

do we send the ipn location url and our customer PayPal account info in the post variables?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as processing the payment on their PayPal account, you can go about this 2 different ways.  You can either use their API credentials and pass those over in the API call and the payment will be processed on their account.  Second option would be to have them grant 3rd party API permissions to your API to be able to process transactions on their account.  Then you would just pass over your API credentials in your API call and also pass over their email address of their PayPal account in the variable "SUBJECT".  This will then process the payment on their account.

As for still haveing the IPN POST sent to your script, you will just need to pass over the IPN URL in the API call.  When pass it over in the API call, it will override whatever is set in the account.  For example, if you are using NVP the variable would be "NOTIFYURL".

Comment: Chad, this is working now, thank you. However, when the customer PayPal store shows and is done being paid for it doesnt auto return. i put the 'return' in the post, but you can only return by clicking the paypal provided link - "return to customer store'. i dont want every client setting up "auto return' in their profile. is their another setting we need in the post to "<input type='hidden' name='????..." for it to auto return after 5 seconds? again this is their paypal account not ours that needs to auto return, using our PayPal it works fine. but we have the profile set for it. thanks!

Comment: Auto return would need to be set in the account, and you can pass over the auto return url in the code.  If its not working, I would need to look at the account and the code that you are using.  Also keep in mind if paying with a credit card, it will not auto return.  The buyer will need to click a link to be returned back to the merchant website.